# How do you create a tail end on an arrow using sthe string "*"?

Tags: java, string

THe question might seem confusing, but the gist of it is that I need to make an arrow for, say, n = 3, which would look like

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

I want to add a tail to this triangle to make it into an arrow. It has to be length (n-1). So:

```
  *
  **
*****
  **
  *
```

Here my code so far, which only gets you the triangle. I can't seem to figure out how to get the tail on the arrow. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
public class Arrow
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
 double n=0;
 if (args.length < 1){ 
    System.out.println("Input a number"); 
    System.exit(0); // Terminate the program if user has not input a number
  }
  else
    n = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 

  String text = "*";
  int n1 = (int) n;
  System.out.println(text);
  for (int x = 1; x < n1; x++) {
     System.out.println(text += "*");
  }

  for (int i = (n1-1); i>0; i--) {
     System.out.println(text = text.substring(0, text.length()-1));
  }
```

}
}

Comment: On rows other than r=3, start the row with the appropriate number of spaces. On row r=3, start it with that many asterisks. Just try to break the question down to it basic elements and hopefully you'll find that each of those elements is doable on its own.

Comment: I say, don't `println` for your first for loop, just output. Then put an if-else after print, and if `x = n1` then output `n1 - 1` more asterisks, then move to a new line, else just move to a new line.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the spaces. I'll post a solution later, but the idea is the same. This might actually be something for the Code Golf SE :)

Answer (score 0):

Code like that is much easier to write if you write the repetitive code in a reusable helper method.

That is called the DRY principle ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

In this case you want to print repeating characters of `'*'` for the arrow, and repeating characters of `' '` (space) for the indentation. So, write a method for creating a `String` of repeated characters:

```
private static String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill(buf, ch);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

Now that you have that, printing a right-arrow is suddenly a lot easier:

```
private static void printRightArrow(char ch, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - 1) + repeat(ch, i));
    System.out.println(repeat(ch, n * 2 - 1));
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - 1) + repeat(ch, i));
}
```

*Test and Output*

```
printRightArrow('*', 3);
printRightArrow('#', 7);
```

```
  *
  **
*****
  **
  *
```

```
      #
      ##
      ###
      ####
      #####
      ######
#############
      ######
      #####
      ####
      ###
      ##
      #
```

Printing arrows in the other direction is very similar:

```
private static void printLeftArrow(char ch, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - i) + repeat(ch, i));
    System.out.println(repeat(ch, n * 2 - 1));
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - i) + repeat(ch, i));
}
private static void printUpArrow(char ch, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - i) + repeat(ch, i * 2 - 1));
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - 1) + ch);
}
private static void printDownArrow(char ch, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - 1) + ch);
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', n - i) + repeat(ch, i * 2 - 1));
}
```

*Test and Output*

```
printRightArrow('*', 5);
printLeftArrow('*', 5);
printUpArrow('*', 5);
printDownArrow('*', 5);
```

```
    *
    **
    ***
    ****
*********
    ****
    ***
    **
    *
```

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*********
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
    *
    *
    *
    *
```

```
    *
    *
    *
    *
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not as robust as Andreas' solution, but it is much like yours. I have just added some for loops and if-else statements.

```
class Arrow {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double n = 0;
        if (args.length < 1){ 
            System.out.println("Input a number"); 
            System.exit(0); // Terminate the program if user has not input a number
        }
        else
            n = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); 

        String text = "";
        int n1 = (int) n;
        for (int x = 0; x < n1; x++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n1 - 1; i++) {
                if (x != n1 - 1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(text += "*");
        }

        for (int i = (n1-1); i>0; i--) {
            for (int j = (n1 - 1); j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(text = text.substring(0, text.length()-1));
        }
    }
}
```